# JPA/Hibernate/HSQLDB querying but not assigning sub-object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I am having trouble with this query but ONLY under HSQLDB. We use Oracle for production database and HSQL for automated integration tests. Here's my main object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENTS")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy(lazy=false)
public class Student implements Serializable {
...
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="STUDENTID",referencedColumnName="ID")
   private Set<StudentRace> races;
...
}
```

StudentRace looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENTRACE")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy(lazy=false)
public class StudentRace implements Serializable {
...
    @Column(name="STUDENTID")
    private Integer studentid;
...
}
```

And my JPA query is like this:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select distinct s from Student s left join fetch s.races "+
  "where s.schoolNumber = :schoolNumber");
```

I know I have correct data in the HSQLDB database - I can manually do a query and see the data. Yet the Student objects always have "races" as null. As I said, this query works fine in Oracle. Is there some kind of HSQLDB setup thing I'm missing?

Edit: Like this? In Student:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="id")
private Set<StudentRace> races;
```

In StudentRace:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="STUDENTID")
private Student student;
```

Still no luck. The "races" element is still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is incorrect, because the `STUDENTRACE.STUDENTID` column is mapped twice: once as a JoinColumn in `Student`, and once as a column in `StudentRace`.

Either make the association unidirectional and remove the studentid field in `StudentRace`, or make it bidirectional, and have a `Student student` field in `StudentRace`, mapped as a ManyToOne, as shown in [this example from the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional).